# sql where condition for getting the first and second maxium values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on SQL and I have the following problem:

```
    select * from(
    select tname,teacher.tid,grade from teacher 
    inner join
    _view
    on(_view.tid=teacher.tid))as D
    group by grade
    where // what should I do here to get the rows having the first and the second   maxium values?
    order by grade desc,tid;
```

I want to select only the rows that have the first maxium value and the second maxium value
, I have tried a lot of thing since yesterday but no benfits from that!!

when I use some thing like MAX,COUNT or AND I get an ERROR of aggregate function, plaese help me with that because I did all I could !!

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULTSET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok after too much thinking I got this to work right and smooth, more over TOP would not work just LIMIT in the end of the query , here is my answer:

```
select * from(
select tname,teacher.tid,grade from teacher 
inner join
_view
on(_view.tid=teacher.tid)
)as D
where grade in(select grade from  _view order by grade desc limit 2)
order by grade desc,tid;
```

thanks everybody for your collaboration.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ORDER BY grade  DESC LIMIT 2
```

Comment: @flashdisk Yeh,I`m blind apparently.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can do:

```
select tname,teacher.tid,grade 
from teacher 
inner join _view on _view.tid=teacher.tid
order by grade desc,tid
limit 2;
```

LIMIT 2 gets you the two first rows of the list you just got from the SELECT. Since you have order by grade desc, the records with two highest grades are going to be returned.

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html):

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned
>   by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments,
>   which must both be nonnegative integer constants (except when using
>   prepared statements).

You were also doing a derived query, but i can't see why you would need it if you are not doing anything with it. And the GROUP BY shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @flashdisk. I'm sorry. i can't understand what you mean